# Replace fasta headers using sed command

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a fasta file which looks like this.

```
>header1  
ATGC....  
>header2  
ATGC...
```

My list files looks like this

```
organism1  
organism2
```

and contains a list of organism  that I want to replace the header with.

I tried to use a `for` loop using `sed` command which is as follows:

```
for i in `cat list7b`; do sed "s/^>/$i/g" sequence.fa; done
```

but it didn't work please tell how I can achieve this task.

The result file should look like this

```
>organism1  
ATGC...  
>organism2  
ATGC....
```

that is `>header1` replaced with `>organism_1` and so on

1. The two headers are distinguished from ATGC as header always starts with `>` greater than sign whereas ATGC would not. That's how they are distinguished.
2. The header lines should be replaced by the order of appearance, i.e. first `header*` replaced with first-line from file, 2nd header from the second and so on.

I also request to explain the logic if possible.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain how you distinguish the `header1`, `header2` etc lines from the `ATGC....` lines. I assume the two lines `organism1`and `organism2` are your file `list7b`. How do you define which `organism*` line shall replace which `header*` line? By a common trailing number, e.g. `header` **1** -> `organism` **1** etc? Or by the order of appearance, i.e. first `header*` replaced with first line from file, 2nd `header*` with 2nd line etc?

Comment: @Bodo Thank you for your quick response. I have re-edited the question and I hope this would help you to understand the problem. Please feel free to ask if the edit is not sufficient, your time and efforts for helping me are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk` this is easy to do in one run.

Assuming your fasta file is named `sequence.fa` and your organisms list file is named `list7b` as in the question you can use

```
awk 'NR == FNR { o[n++] = $0; next } /^>/ && i < n { $0 = ">" o[i++] } 1' list7b sequence.fa > output.fa
```

Explanation:

`NR == FNR` is a condition for doing something with the first file only. (total number of records is equal to number of records in current file)

`{ o[n++] = $0; next }` puts the input line into array `o`, counts the entries and skips further processing of the input line, so `o` will contain all your organism lines.

The next part is executed for the remaining file(s).

`/^>/ && i < n` is valid for lines that start with `>` as long as `i` is less than the number of elements `n` that were put into array `o`.

`{ $0 = ">" o[i++] }` replaces the current line with `>` followed by the array element (i.e. a line from the first file) and increments the index `i` to the next element.

`1` is an "always true" condition with the implicit default action `{ print }` to print the current line for every input line.

Comment: Thank you very much @bodo I appreciate your help and precious time it helped me a lot.